# Delphi encryption algorithm

Tags: delphi, encryption

I use this code to encrypt files:

```
procedure TForm9.EnDecryptFile(pathin, pathout: string; mem:TMemo; Chave: Word);
    var
       InMS, OutMS: TMemoryStream;
       cnt: Integer;
       C,A,B: byte;
       s:string;
     begin
       mem.Clear;
       InMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
       OutMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         InMS.LoadFromFile(pathin) ;
         InMS.Position := 0;
         for cnt := 0 to InMS.Size - 1 do
           begin
             InMS.Read(C, 1) ;
             A:=c;
             C := (C xor not (ord(chave shr cnt))) ;
             mem.Lines.Add(IntToStr(A)+^I+IntToStr(C));
             OutMS.Write(C, 1) ;
           end;
     OutMS.SaveToFile(pathout) ;
   finally
     InMS.Free;
     OutMS.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

I DON'T Understand algorithm at all when I Add a meme control in form and check about 2000 bytes before/after encryption. Please help me to understand this headlines:

- Combination of Xor and not Operation.

PLAESE USE EXAMPLE TO SHOW ALGORITHM OPERATIONS. THANKS.

Comment: Rather than us documenting the language fundamentals, why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: You have seen e.g. this q: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482352/simple-text-file-encryption-based-on-a-key" and its comments + answers?

Comment: Sorry! I have problem with combinations of XOR and NOT please help in this step.

Comment: First, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher.  XOR encoding/decoding combines the bits of a byte with the bits of the key.  XORing the byte with the same key twice restores it to what it was. The "not (ord(chave shr cnt))" generates the key from position of the byte in InMS which is being encrypted/decrypted and the value of Chave.  Put a breakpoint on that line and watch it happen in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me to understand the combination of `xor` and `not` operations.

I take it from your update that you understand the individual operators meaning, but are unsure about how the expression

```
C xor not (ord(chave shr cnt))
```

is interpreted.

The meaning of this expression is determined by [operator precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence). As you can see from that link, `not` has higher precedence than `xor`. So in

```
C := (C xor not (ord(chave shr cnt)));
```

the `not` is evaluated, and then the `xor`. This assignment is equivalent to:

```
A := ord(chave shr cnt);
B := not A;
C := C xor B;
```

Note that in the code in the question, the outer parentheses in

```
C := (C xor not (ord(chave shr cnt)));
```

are spurious and can be removed. Indeed that line of code could be written as:

```
C := C xor not ord(chave shr cnt);
```

Although it is arguably clearer to be explicit about precedence in this case and write:

```
C := C xor (not ord(chave shr cnt));
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I understand.all this violence was not necessary David Heffernan.

Comment: There was no violence. We just tried to work out what you were asking. At first it seemed like you did not know what any other operators mean. Then with the edits it became clear that precedence was the key. It's easy to misunderstand when you just have written word. For instance, in my culture ALL CAPITAL TEXT is considered to be rude but I think you just aren't aware of that. So we made nothing of it.

Comment: David, Why chave shr cnt return Byte(less than 256). chave define as word and cnt sefine as integer.

Comment: Don't know. Can't see that code. Not in the question. I think I answered the question you asked. Of course, `65535 shr 10 < 256`, for instance.

Comment: 65,535 in binary = 1111 1111 1111 1111
shift right 10 times return = 63 in binary = 0011 1111
what happend? I'm confused.

Comment: 10 zero bits got pushed in from the left.

Comment: I check Bitwise operation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation but not find any instruction about your comment. Could you reference me to complete tutorial on programming web sites.

Comment: That document you link to describes it. Delphi `shr` is logical right shift.