# How can I apply a simple XOR encryption/decryption mechanism in Delphi with no third party packages?

Tags: delphi, encryption, cryptography, xor

How can I apply a file encryption/decryption mechanism correctly in Delphi?

I found a very old source that supposedly teaches how to do just that, but using strings. After my previous question here, that doesn't appear to be the correct approach. Rather I should perform byte operations. This is what my old source proposes:

1-) Read the file using the old binded C function:

```
function ReadFile(path: String): AnsiString;
var
  file: File;
  type: Byte;
begin
  type:= FileMode;
  try
    FileMode := 0;
    AssignFile(file, path);
{$I-}
    Reset(file, 1);
{$I+}
    if IOResult = 0 then
      try
        SetLength(Result, FileSize(file));

        if Length(Result) > 0 then

        begin
{$I-}
          BlockRead(file, Result[1], Length(Result));
{$I+}
          if IOResult <> 0 then
            Result := '';
        end;
      finally
        CloseFile(file);
      end;
  finally
    FileMode := type;
  end;
end;
```

2-)
Apply the XOR operations character by character on this huge AnsiString, like so:

```
 function Xor(Buffer: String; Key: integer): String;
  var
    i, c, x: integer;
  begin
    for i := 1 to Length(Buffer) do
    begin
      c := integer(Buffer[i]);
      x := c xor Key;
      Result := Result + Char(x);
    end;
  end;
```

But the problem afterwards, and is what my source does *NOT* show, is how to convert this transformed string back to bytes so I can have a functional resource to write back to a new decrypted file.

Apparently this is not the correct approach to encrypt and decrypt a file. Can someone please explain to me the correct approach to properly:

*Read a file, apply a basic XOR encryption mechanism and then be able to read this file again, decrypt it and use this VALID binary (DLL, EXE) data to write back into a new decrypted file?*

Comment: The whole point of XOR "encryption" is that if you do a bitwise XOR of one byte with another twice, you get the original byte back.

Comment: Basically: open the source and destination files  (e.g. with [`TFileStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TFileStream)). Read a block of bytes in a buffer. Apply XOR. Write the buffer to the destination file.  Repeat until end of file.

Comment: Don't use strings to store binary data!  Use a byte array.  Strings are for readable characters.  Many bytes are not readable and will not be preserved by a data type intended for holding readable characters.  You're also mixing `string` and `AnsiString` types.  You don't say which version of Delphi you are using, but `string` in anything newer than D2007 is a unicode type, which further complicates its abuse as a byte array container.  (ie: `integer(Buffer[i])` can be >255).

Comment: I'm using a rather modern version of Delphi 10 >. So I don't think the AnsiString conversion would be a problem

Comment: Do NOT use AnsiString nor any string for this encryption program. Use an array of bytes. If your files are not to big (A few MB at most), you can use a TMemoryStream, call LoadFromFile, iterate thru the Memory property using the Size property, apply the XOR and then SaveToFile. You are done!

Comment: This is your second question on the subject, and it still isn't clear to me if your problem is that : 1. You don't know how to save data to disk. 2. You don't know XOR is a symetric operation. 3. Maybe something else...

Comment: This isn't encryption. And encryption operates on byte arrays not text. You are making a classic mistake in believing that you can do this without gaining knowledge.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9482352/2292722) and it's answers answer your question?

Comment: Looking at your other question (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244734/how-does-malware-avoid-avs-when-using-a-simple-dll-injection-technique) I am afraid you are trying to write a malware. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "simple xor encryption" will not improve security of an application.  Make sure to add a comment informing any reader that this performs no security benefit, as it might confuse another developer into thinking that it raises the bar against an attacker.  If this was a security system then you would need to use AES for encryption or SHA-256/SHA3 for hashing, or PBKDF2/Scrypt for password storage.

That being said, GitHub search is powerful, here is some delphi code that obfuscates bits:
https://github.com/EonaCat/NightBitsEncryptor/blob/master/NightBitsEncryptor.pas

The above code is (in)security though obscurity and must never be used as a security system.

Comment: I check this link and this unit does not answer correctly.